# SQL Server 2014 update numeric without rounding

Tags: sql-server-2014

In my project in SQL Server 2014, I am creating a table on the fly with

```
select  
    Region_Code, 
    '9999999' as [Avg Time to Dispatch in Minutes],
    999999999.9999 as [Avg Time to Dispatch in Hours]
from
    table1
into 
    TempTable1
```

I notice when I look at the design view of this table I created that the 3rd column is of type `Numeric(13,4)`.

I then update this table with real values and get:

```
region      AvgTimeToDispatchInMinutes  AvgTimeToDispatchInHours
Maine       393                         999999999.9999
```

I want to get the `AvgTimeToDispatchInHours` so I do:

```
UPDATE TempTable1
SET [Avg Time to Dispatch in Hours] = [Avg Time to Dispatch in Minutes] / 60
```

I am getting 6.00 instead of 6.6 which is what I want.

How can I get 6.6 or the number not being rounded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing an **integer** division:

```
SELECT 393 / 60
```

results in `6` as you said (because it answers the question: *how many times can 60 fit in 393 wholly?*).

If you need fractional values, you need to convert at least one of the numbers involved to a fractional type, e.g. `decimal` - the easiest would be like this:

```
SELECT 393 / 60.0
```

which returns 6.55 as expected